# The satellite map called by Google Map Api is saved to the local disk using python's urllib package and an error is reported

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps-api-3

I use google map static map api to get a satellite image and want to store in my local harddisk , but the python got `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060]`

here is my code, is really simple, thanks!

```
 import urllib
 import urllib.request as ur
 # picture back from Google Static Map Api
 img_src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&center=31.403874,115.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=############'
 ur.urlretrieve(img_src, 'D:/G.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to share your API key publicly. This works fine.
Error code 10060 means it cannot connect to the source. Check your network.

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=2&center=31.403874,115.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=#####'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'D:/map.png')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, As you said, the problem is indeed due to the network, I have to use VPN to connect google map API, do you have any idea to handle this problem?